# Unittest run a test only if the previous one is a success

Tags: python, unit-testing, flask

I am writing test cases for my  CRUD  flask app https://github.com/Leo-g/Flask-Skeleton/blob/master/tests.py

I want to ensure that the update and delete tests run only if the add tests succeeds.

```
def test_add(self):
            rv = self.app.post('/users/add', data=dict(name = 'test name', email = 'test@email.com'), follow_redirects=True)

            assert 'Add was successful' in rv.data.decode('utf-8')


def test_Update(self):

             with app.app_context():
                id = Users.query.first().id
                rv = self.app.post('/users/update/{}'.format(id), data=dict(name = 'test name update', email = 'test@email.update'), follow_redirects=True)
                assert 'Update was successful' in rv.data.decode('utf-8')
```

While reading the docs I see that this can be done via the unittest.skip decorator but I am not sure How I can implement it.

Comment: Advice: In general, tests are run without order (e.g. they may be paralleled), therefore your test design is simply wrong.

Comment: According to the docs, the tests will be run in alphabetical order

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `--failfast` command-line option when running the tests to make the test suite stop after a single test fails. For example, if you normally run the tests with the command `python -m unittest` you can change it to `python -m unittest --failfast`.